# Works in Google charts but not in Eastwood?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

This chart works fine in Google charts, but when rendered in Eastwood, it doesn't use the 2nd provided color, rather it applies the first color to both bars in the chart.

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=150x150&chd=t:18,81&chco=FFF000|00FFFF&chxt=x,y&chl=Bar1|Bar2&chtt=Chart
```

Any suggestions as to why this could be? Unfortunately it looks like Eastwood is somewhat abandoned.

Comment: Sorry, what the heck is Eastwood :)?

Comment: Eastwood is a Google Charts compatible alternative running on JFree charts: http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed in my 1.1.0 Eastwood installation.  It should be noted that the author doesn't have time to do releases anymore, but he's given commit access to others who are patching with bugs regularly.

You can get the latest and greatest with:

```
svn co https://eastwood.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/eastwood eastwood
```

Unfortunately, the problem is still present in the trunk, and they also broke backward compatibility with Google Charts API (graphs just don't look the same; they tried to add some colorization effects).

I tried to dig through the Eastwood trunk to see what was going wrong, but the code is a complete mess of spaghetti.  I don't know enough about Tomcat servlets to do much more debugging right now.  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.